# Creating a simple Login and Authentication system in angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, authentication

I am new to web developing and angularjs and I am creating a simple application for manage user, bill, ecc, ecc.
I have finally reached the end of this app, the only thing missing is a login and an authentication system.
I have read a lot about login and authentication system with angularjs and all the guide i've followed are difficult for me.
Do you have something simple to suggest? I am searching something that allow me to limit views in base of user's role

As backend I am actually using Java

Comment: "All the guides are difficult"? There are tons of relatively easy guides out there

Answer (score 0):

The front end shouldn't really care, I just register an  angular inteceptor to look for 401 Not Authorized on any http call. Then, I call a e.g. showLogin function which shows/ hides my login page. I like to keep my  widget right in the html (not be a route). This is good, since if the user goes to e.g. /users and is not logged in, I intercept (leaving the url as is) and show my login page (Full screen) which is an angular.component. Then I just hide it after logging in.

This is a better approach then having a /login route and dealing with round tripping the url that they originally wanted. my main index.html looks like:

```
<body><login></login><main ui-view></main></body>
```